# Why the `h-full`/`height:100%` does not fill the empty hole for a div element?

Tags: html, css, next.js, flexbox, tailwind-css

The problem is that I have a *title* a *subtitle* and a *footer*. I would like the *subtitle*'s div to span across the empty space between the *title* and the *footer*.

I tried setting `h-full` to the div but it does not seem to do anything.

```js
export default function ASD() {
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col justify-start mx-auto w-9/12 min-h-screen bg-red-300 text-center">
      <div className="bg-yellow-200">
        <div className="bg-blue-200 text-6xl">
          <h1>Title</h1>
        </div>
        <div className="bg-indigo-500 text-3xl">
          <h1>Subtitle</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <footer className="mt-auto bg-green-200">Footer</footer>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Also, I would like the whole page to cover the entire screen so that the *footer* is at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `header` and `subtitle` is wrapped inside a `div`, you need to remove that wrapper div ,and then use `flex-1` so that the subtitle div spans accross the entire height of the screen.

```
<div class="mx-auto flex min-h-screen w-9/12 flex-col justify-start bg-red-300 text-center">
  <div class="bg-blue-200 text-6xl">
    <h1>Title</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-1 bg-indigo-500 text-3xl">  // use flex-1 here
    <h1>Subtitle</h1>
  </div>

  <footer class="mt-auto bg-green-200">Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Output:

[image]

[Tailwind play link](https://play.tailwindcss.com/Wpj7izkqNF)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    <div className="flex flex-col justify-start mx-auto w-9/12 h-full bg-red-300 text-center">
      <div className="bg-yellow-200 flex-1 flex flex-col">
        <div className="bg-blue-200 text-6xl">
          <h1>Title</h1>
        </div>
        <div className="bg-indigo-500 text-3xl flex-1">
          <h1>Subtitle</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <footer className="bg-green-200">Footer</footer>
    </div>
```